# Cannot add key in matinee for static meshes (UE4)

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

My problem is the following:
I was trying to make a sliding door based on a video tutorial, I had the static mesh, which was the door itself, and I added a Matinee for that door, so I went 'Add New Empty Group -> Add Movement Track', so I had the door with a movement track, but when I tried to add a key, I couldn't. 
This was the error message: "Nothing to keyframe, or selected object can't be keyframed on this type of track." 
And I only get this message when I try to add keys in the movement track of a static mesh. When it's a camera, everything is fine.
Any idea why this is happening, and how I can solve this?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

To animate a Static Mesh in Matinee, you need to change it to Movable. 
This can be done by selecting the mesh, and under the Details panel, changing the Mobility option from Static to Movable.
Then you are able to keyframe it on a movement track.

Cheers,
MAK777